# Non-root SSH key authentication problems with DSM 6

Tags: ssh, openssh, synology

With Synology DSM 6 it seems that SSH requires users to be members of the `admin` group.

However, even in this case there seem to be problems with file/directory permissions that prevent key-based authentication succeeding for non-root users (standard `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` works OK for root).

Specifically, SSH key-based authentication fails even with a correct `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` in place.

Answer (score 0):

#### Intro - Debugging SSH

First up, helpful note (for me anyway) when debugging SSH auth issues:

1. Run a server in debug mode on the Synology:

   ```
   /bin/sshd -d -p 1234` as root;
   ```
2. Log in from your client using

   ```
   ssh -p1234 -v <username>@<synology>
   ```

This will enable you to get easy access to helpful debug.

#### Step 1 - Update `sshd` configuration

Edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and update the `AuthorizedKeysFile` configuration to support default *plus* alternate file location:

```
AuthorizedKeysFile /var/ssh-homes/%u/dot-ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys
```

Restart SSH server, most easily achieved in this case via the DSM GUI:

Steps: *untick 'Enable SSH' --> apply --> re-tick --> apply*

[image: Terminal settings on Control Panel]

#### Step 2 - Create alternate `authorized_keys` file for each applicable user

I created the script below as `/root/prepare-dot-ssh-authorized-keys` for this purpose as follows:

1. Edit using `vi /root/prepare-dot-ssh-authorized-keys` or similar
2. Make executable with `chmod u+x /root/prepare-dot-ssh-authorized-keys`
3. Run with Synology user name `/root/prepare-dot-ssh-authorized-keys <username>`

#### References

Note there was some helpful discussion on the Synology forums [Non-root SSH key authentication working with DSM 6.2.2-24922 Update 4](https://community.synology.com/enu/forum/1/post/129890) and [ssh server refused key for all users but root](https://community.synology.com/enu/forum/17/post/110983) which saved me some time and put me on the right track.

#### Script `/root/prepare-dot-ssh-authorized-keys`

```
#!/bin/bash -e

# https://community.synology.com/enu/forum/1/post/129890

if test -z "$1" ; then
    echo "usage: $0 <username>"
    echo ""
    echo "Ensure config in /etc/ssh/sshd_config includes:"
    echo "AuthorizedKeysFile /var/ssh-homes/%u/dot-ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys"
    exit 1
fi

_DIR="/var/ssh-homes/$1/dot-ssh"
_AK="${_DIR}/authorized_keys"

if test -d "${_DIR}" ; then
    echo "$0: ${_DIR} already exists"
    exit 2
fi

if test -r "${_AK}" ; then
    echo "$0: ${_AK} already exists"
    exit 3
fi

mkdir -p "${_DIR}"
chmod og-rwx `dirname "${_DIR}"`

touch "${_AK}"
chown "${1}.users" -R `dirname "${_DIR}"`

echo "$0: created ${_AK}"
```